# Virtualbox VM as a systemd service

Tags: virtualbox, systemd

I would like to start a specific Virtualbox VM when the host starts and shut it down properly when the host shuts down.

I tried to create a simple systemd service file as the following:

```
[Unit]
Description=Start and shutdown VBox VMs
Requires=systemd-modules-load.service
After=systemd-modules-load.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/VBoxManage startvm "test" --type headless
ExecStop=/usr/bin/VBoxManage controlvm "test" acpipowerbutton

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The strange thing is that the start part works but the stop part doesn't. I'm a noob in systemd. Could you please help?

Comment: The ExecStop command may not be suitable... As the [manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) explains: *Note that it is usually not sufficient to specify a command for this setting that only asks the service to terminate (for example, by queuing some form of termination signal for it), but does not wait for it to do so. Since the remaining processes of the services are killed using SIGKILL immediately after the command exited, this would not result in a clean stop. The specified command should hence be a synchronous operation, not an asynchronous one.*

Comment: Maybe `ExecStop=/usr/bin/VBoxManage controlvm "test"  savestate` works better?

Comment: I tried ExecStop=/usr/bin/VBoxManage controlvm "test" savestate but the problem is that when I run systemctl start vboxvm.service, it's like both start and stop are executed and it leaves the VM in a saved state. When I start the VM manually and then run systemctl stop vboxvm.service, it does nothing.

Comment: OK, I followed this [link]http://www.ericerfanian.com/automatically-starting-virtualbox-vms-on-archlinux-using-systemd/ and it worked except that when I reboot the host, the guest doesn't get started. Any ideas?